# GroupBy with many-to-many relationship in EFCore

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

Products:

```
+------+---------+--------------+
|  id  |  name   | status       |
+------+---------+--------------+
| 1    |  foo    | in stock     |
| 2    |  bar    | in stock     |
| 3    |  baz    | out of stock |
+------+---------+--------------+
```

Items:

```
+------+---------+--------+
|  id  |  name   |  Cost  |
+------+---------+--------+
| 1    |  item1  | 10     |
| 2    |  item2  | 20     |
| 3    |  item3  | 5      |
+------+---------+--------+
```

Intermediate table:

```
+--------------+------------+
|  product_id  |  items_id  |
+--------------+------------+
|  1           | 1          |
|  1           | 3          |
|  2           | 2          |
+--------------+------------+
```

Many to many configuration:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .HasMany<Item>(x => x.Items)
    .WithMany(y => y.Products)
    .UsingEntity(p => p.ToTable("ProductItems"));
```

Result should be:

```
{
    'TotalItems': 3,
    'Items': [
       { 'Status': 'in stock', 'Cost': 30 },
       { 'Status': 'out of stock', 'Cost': 5 }
    ]
}
```

Total count of items for a specific product:

```
context.Products
      .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("foo"))
      .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
      .Count();
```

Now I want to group the items per product status. Something like:

```
context.Products
      .Where(x => x.Name.Equals("foo"))
      .SelectMany(x => x.Items)
      .GroupBy(Status, (g,x) => new {
          Status = ...
          Cost = ...
      })
      .ToList()
```

Any ideas how to achieve the desired output?

Comment: Can you show the entity classes?

Comment: @vernou updated my question with the entity classes.

Comment: Two products have the id 1. Is it desired?

Comment: @vernou just a typo

Comment: Can you show how is configured the many to many relationship?

Comment: The product 1 is in stock with the item 1 (cost 10) and 3 (cost 15), but in the result the status 'in stock' has the cost 30.

Comment: Your current data does not have a link to the product id 3 and thus no "out of stock" cost associated with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution with intermediate entity**

Entities:

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
    public DbSet<ProductItem> ProductsItems => Set<ProductItem>();
    public DbSet<Item> Items => Set<Item>();        

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<ProductItem>()
            .HasKey(pi => new { pi.ProductId, pi.ItemId });
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(p => p.Items)
            .WithOne(pi => pi.Product)
            .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.ProductId);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Item>()
            .HasMany(i => i.Products)
            .WithOne(pi => pi.Item)
            .HasForeignKey(pi => pi.ItemId);
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public List<ProductItem> Items { get; set; }
}

public class ProductItem
{
    public int ProductId { get; set; }
    public Product Product { get; set; }
    public int ItemId { get; set; }
    public Item Item { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public List<ProductItem> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Query :

```cs
var totalProducts = context.Products.Count();
var totalItems = context.Items.Count();
var items = context.Products
    .Join(context.ProductsItems, p => p.Id, pi => pi.ProductId, (p, pi) => new { p.Status, pi.ItemId })
    .Join(context.Items, si => si.ItemId, i => i.Id, (si, i) => new { si.Status, i.Cost })
    .GroupBy(p => p.Status, (s, pis) => new {
    Status = s,
    Cost = pis.Sum(pi => pi.Cost)
}).ToList();
```

SQL Generated :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Products] AS [p]

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Items] AS [i]

SELECT [p].[Status], COALESCE(SUM([i].[Cost]), 0.0) AS [Cost]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
INNER JOIN [ProductsItems] AS [p0] ON [p].[Id] = [p0].[ProductId]
INNER JOIN [Items] AS [i] ON [p0].[ItemId] = [i].[Id]
GROUP BY [p].[Status]
```

**Solution without intermediate entity**

Entities :

```cs
public class MyContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Product> Products => Set<Product>();
    public DbSet<Item> Items => Set<Item>();

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany<Item>(x => x.Items)
            .WithMany(y => y.Products)
            .UsingEntity(p => p.ToTable("ProductItems"));
    }
}

public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public List<Item> Items { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Query :

```cs
var totalProducts = context.Products.Count();
var totalItems = context.Items.Count();
var items = context.Products
    .SelectMany(p => p.Items.Select(i => new { p.Status, i.Cost }))
    .GroupBy(p => p.Status, (s, ps) => new {
        Status = s,
        Cost = ps.Sum(i => i.Cost)
    })
    .ToList();
```

SQL Generated :

```sql
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Products] AS [p]

SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM [Items] AS [i]

SELECT [t].[Status], COALESCE(SUM([t].[Cost]), 0.0) AS [Cost]
FROM [Products] AS [p]
CROSS APPLY (
  SELECT [p].[Status], [i].[Cost]
  FROM [ProductItems] AS [p0]
  INNER JOIN [Items] AS [i] ON [p0].[ItemsId] = [i].[Id]
  WHERE [p].[Id] = [p0].[ProductsId]
) AS [t]
GROUP BY [t].[Status]
```

Comment: Thx for helping. I had to change my question significantly. The relationship is actually a many to many relationship.

Comment: I updated my answer to reflect the updated question.

Comment: Thx again! I don't have context.ProductItems. I updated my question with the many-to-many entity configuration.

Comment: I added a solution without intermediate entity.

Answer (score 1):

you can create two dto like below and use groupby to do that

```
public class ItemDTO
{
    public int Status { get; set; }
    public decimal Cost { get; set; }
}

public class productDTO
{
    public int TotalProducts { get; set; }
    public int TotalItems { get; set; }
    public List<ItemDTO> Items { get; set; }
}
```

then use this

```
var grouped = products.GroupBy(x => x.Status).Select(x =>new
        {
            key = x.Key,
            value = x.ToList()
        });
var res = new productDTO
        {
            TotalProducts = products.Count,
            TotalItems = products.Sum(x => x.Items?.Count)??0,
            Items = grouped.Select(x => new ItemDTO
            {
                Cost = x.value.Sum(q => q.Items?.Sum(i => i.Cost)??0),
                Status = x.key
            }).ToList()
        };
```

Comment: Thx for helping. I had to change my question significantly. The relationship is actually a many to many relationship.